# Eclipse IDE - Unable to connect to mysql database

Tags: java, mysql, eclipse

I tried to map the driver connector file from the reference library to the project file, but still gives the error.
Please could you help me connected to mysql database?

MySQL Connector for Java: mysql-connector-java-8.0.30.jar (added to the Java Build Path correctly)
JRE: jre-7u51-windows-i586.exe

PS: the DB is running perfectly in the MySQL workbench.

SC:

```
public static void connect() {
    try{
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        dbURL = "jdbc:mysql://";
        adresseServeur="localhost:3306/";
        bddNAME="School_DB";
        String username="root";
        String pw="root";
        con = DriverManager.getConnection(dbURL + adresseServeur + bddNAME , username , pw);
    }catch(Exception ex){
        ex.printStackTrace();
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"ERROR 01" + "\n", "Erreur système!",JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
    }
}
```

ERROR MSG:

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException: Could not create connection to database server.
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:377)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:360)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:956)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:935)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:924)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:870)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:2311)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2064)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:790)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection.<init>(JDBC4Connection.java:44)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:377)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:395)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:325)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at pack_School.School_Main.connect(School_Main.java:46)
    at pack_School.School_Main.main(School_Main.java:23)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getServerCharset(ConnectionImpl.java:2983)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendConnectionAttributes(MysqlIO.java:1873)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.proceedHandshakeWithPluggableAuthentication(MysqlIO.java:1802)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.doHandshake(MysqlIO.java:1206)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.coreConnect(ConnectionImpl.java:2234)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:2265)
    ... 14 more
```

Comment: Perhaps a driver released in 2022 requires a version of Java not already years past its end of life? Retry it with at least Java 8 or 11.

Comment: I'm getting the same error.  I'm deploying to a Tomcat9 server running on Ubuntu 22, using Java 11.  None of these is "end of life".  @Shadow, did you ever get this figured out?